# Is it possible to push data to my mobile application through Parse.com object?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push

I'm trying to use parse.com in one of my project. But I'd like to know if it's possible to get notification in my mobile application (iOS, android) when there is a change in an object, for example, a new raw is added, or a raw is modified?

The query is used to get the object currently. But this is not very efficient in my case. I have to query the result every 30s and disable the cache for the query. But the object is seldom changed in one hand. And I don't want the end user to wait for too long to be notified when there is a change if I set the interval to bigger value on the other hand.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: How/when are the objects being changed/added?

Comment: Normally object is manually created in parse.com website before it can be used.

Comment: So you are adding it in the data browser yourself, or it is being done by a user in the app?

Comment: I'll add the data in browser by myself. Users are only allowed to view the data and modified the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a push from the method you use to add or edit the data to parse.com for more info https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/REST

Comment: I think you can use their Javascript SDK http://blog.parse.com/2012/10/11/the-javascript-sdk-in-node-js/

Comment: This is really great. But I have one more question. The app id and js key is added to javascript file. Is this secure?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I can use this code in my server js file so that it won't be readable. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It cannot be accessed by outside, since it is in the server